# Cable type identification required

Tags: wiring

I'm not an electrical person, and need to identify the type of wiring used on my Asus adapter for my router.

Beneath the outer insulation is a set of copper bindings that wrap a white insulation layer with another copper wiring in the middle.

Screenshot:

[image]

I need to fix this cable, however, have been told that it's not possible.

Comment: It would help to have a picture of the cable, the damaged area, and the powersupply instead of the shredded bits.

Comment: yes, it is not possible to fix the cable in the picture ... why would you want to anyway, it is only a couple centimeters long

Comment: Sounds like your describing a type of coaxial cable